# How to extract product and version information from Install Shield Script

Tags: installation, installshield

I am installing several ibm products which use Install Shield (Script) as Installation technology.My job is to extract the product name,edition and version information after/before installing the product.If the installation is successful,I can get the product information from vpd.properties.But, most of the products fail to install due to several reasons like pre-requisite failing issue etc.. Can any one give me inputs on how to extract product information from Install Shield Script with out launching the installer.
I did the same for Install Anywhere script and it is working and it extracts product name,version and edition information successfully.

Best Regards,
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

Write a .net exe that has included reference to:

ISWProj21

Now you can call methods that let you get and set all the information you would want from the installshield project file.